# Errors in code using LLList

Tags: java, error-handling, linked-list

I am trying to write code that removes all of one item from a list but am getting an error when I try and use the method that says null pointer exception.
Which line is causing this error and how can I go about fixing it? It should also return true after the items are removed and false if there are no occurrences.

Update: the error is the line Object item2 = trav.item

```
public boolean removeAll(Object item){
    Node trav = head;
    while(trav != null){
        Object item2 = trav.item;
        // it could be `item2.equals` 
        if(item2.equals(item)){
            trav.next = trav;
            return true;
        }
        trav = trav.next; 
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Should we guess where the NullPointerException is located ? Use a debugger (and walk step by step) and you should find the reason.

Comment: I found the line but I'm not sure why I'm getting this exception. It is the Object item2 = trav.item line

Comment: It cannot be this line with this code as the `while` statement would prevent to enter in if `trav` is `null`.

Comment: @tltl you must be mistaken. `trav` cannot be null at that point `while(trav != null) { Object item2 = trav.item;`, therefor there cannot be a NPE on that line.

Comment: the only lines that are outside of the null exception are the Node trav= head and the return

Comment: @tltl what are you talking about "outside of the null exception?"

Comment: fyi aside from the null pointer, I suspect your code to remove the objects is wrong.

Comment: the while(trav != null) includes all but those two lines that I stated

Comment: I fsuspected there were other errors but I need to get it to run first

Comment: @tltl a while loop is not an exception catcher. Only `trav` is guaranteed to not be null at the start of that loop, and it could become null if you ever set `trav = null` (or something that returns null). Anything else could easily be null.

Comment: I suggest replacing `item2.equals(item)` with `item.equals(item2)` *for a start*, since you are the one that passes in `item` and should know if it is null or not.

Comment: thank you, that got rid of the error so now I need to edit my code a little to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my fixing your NPE.

If you are having trouble fixing your removal code then look at this for reference, it has been tested.

I include comments to explain what is happening.

```
public class LList {

    // very basic singly linked node
    class Node {
        public Node next;
        public Object item;
        public Node(Object o) {
            item = o;
        }
    }

    // the head and tail of this list
    Node head = null;
    Node tail = null;

    public boolean removeAll(Object item) {
        int count = 0;
        if (head == null)
            return false;

        // while `head.item.equals(item)` remove the head
        while (head != null && item.equals(head.item)) {
            head = head.next;
            count++;
        }
        // don't need to worry about updating `head` anymore
        // because now `!head.item.equals(item)`, else `head == null`
        if (head == null)
            return count > 0;

        // previous and current nodes
        Node prev = head; // !head.item.equals(item)
        Node curr = head.next;
        while (curr != null) {
            if (item.equals(curr.item)) {
                // to remove `curr` make the previous node skip it
                // and link to the next node instead
                prev.next = curr.next;
                count++;
            } else {
                // if curr was removed then prev stays put
                // otherwise curr is the new prev
                prev = curr;
            }
            // always move curr forward
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return count > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried to code something along the lines of your code. Did not test it though. It might help, it might not. Take it with a grain of salt.

```
public boolean removeAll(Object item) {
        int removeCounter = 0;
        if (head == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (head.value.equals(item)) {
            head = head.next;
            removeCounter++;
        }
        Node previousTrav = head;
        Node trav = head.next;
        while(trav.next != null) {
            if (trav.item.equals(item)) {
                previousTrav.next = trav.next;
                removeCounter++;
            }
            previousTrav = trav;
            trav = trav.next;
        }
        if(removeCounter > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see two problems:

If `item2` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

`trav.next = trav;` produces a circling. In the next call of method `removeAll`, you run into an endless loop. You need to set the next node to the previous node to avoid the circling.

```
public boolean removeAll(Object item) {
    if (item == null} {
        return false;
    } else {
        Node node = head;
        Node prevNode = null;
        boolean result = false;

        while (node != null) {
            Object item2 = node.item;
            if (item.equals(item2)) {
                if (prevNode == null) { // only 1 element in list
                    node = null;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    prevNode.next = node.next;
                }
                result = true;
            }
            prevNode = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I fixed the first problem but I am unsure of how to fix the second

Comment: I added the code. i didn't tested it, so no guarantee. And why the downvote? Bad day?

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted any of the answers, not sure who did that